# How choose array in JSON

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, nsarray

I have some problem in my project. So i used JSON for take some information.
When i have JSON with folders(example: i have NSDictionary with name Playlist in this playlist i have NSString name and album) for this i make this code:

```
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webdata options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *playlist =[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"playlist"];

    for (NSDictionary *diction in playlist) {
        NSDictionary *artist = [diction objectForKey:@"artist"];
        NSDictionary *song = [diction objectForKey:@"song"];
        NSString *name = [artist objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *namesong = [song objectForKey:@"name"];
        [array addObject:name];
        [array2 addObject:namesong];
    }
    [[self tableTrack]reloadData];
}
```

It's work perfect! BUT! When i don't have any folders, only, JSON without NSDictionary only NSStrings, how make? Sorry for my stupid question but really i tried write:

```
NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webdata options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *name = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *namesong = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
    [array addObject:name];
    [array2 addObject:namesong];
}
[[self tableTrack]reloadData];
```

}

But i have error, also my app crashed:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7615c90'

So, what i doing wrong?

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if you include samples of the JSON you are parsing in each case.

Comment: without NSDictionary http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://europaplus.ua/upload/top40.json

Comment: And this parse with NSDictionary http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://europaplus.ua/on_air/onair.json

Comment: NSDictionary - it's Playlist,playing,dis

Comment: Study the JSON syntax at json.org.  It's all there if you think about it.

Comment: learn JSON from http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says you have an NSArray, not an NSDictionary. This corresponds to a JSON array:

```
[
  { "name" : "fred" },
  { "name" : "jane" }
]
```

Here you have an array of dictionaries. You may want:

```
NSArray *people = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webdata options:0 error:nil];

for (NSDictionary *person in people) {
     NSLog(@"name is %@", person[@"name"];
}
```

Comment: How make this without NSDictionary?